# Decorate part of text with border and margin

Tags: react-native

I am trying to decorate part of text in react-native. I managed to add background to part of text using nested `<Text>` component. It looks something like this:

#### Actual:

[image: Actual Decoration]

```
<Text>
    The Python shell used in the terminal is called a
    <Text style={...}>{` ??? `}</Text>
    interpreter.
</Text>
```

But, this doesn't allow you to add border radius, margin or padding. What I'm looking for is something like this:

#### Expected:

[image: Expected Decoration]

Answer (score 0):

Consider use a View, here is a little example:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <Text>The Python shell used in the terminal is called a</Text>
  <View style={{you can apply your style here}}><Text>{` ??? `}</Text></View>
  <Text>interpreter.</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: That was just en example, flex wrap doesn't wrap text properly, only views. It'll sometime leave the whole line empty if the second part of text (after ???) is too big and move it to next line